# Binding to style in my WP7 Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7

in my view, I have a button :

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonTextForwardStyle}" Content="My Text" Width="400" Height="100" />
```

in the app.xaml, I'm trying to define a style that looks like

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTextForwardTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="ButtonTextForwardStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="pressedimage.png"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="image" Source="normalimage.png" Height="80" Width="100" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel> 
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like the content of the button (my text) to be binded to the TextBlock. But it lookis like it's not working.

How can i do that ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TextBlock is inside the Button ControlTemplate, so you may want to use TemplateBinding instead of Binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
```

Comment: that's should be the same thing for other properties as height and width, isn't it ?